# JSON Schema - How to define object in object recursive

Tags: json, validation, recursion, jsonschema

Situation is following:

1.) In an object, I can have a "string", "array" or another "object".

2.) The "array" can contain only "string".

3.) The "object" can contain 1.) which means that I can have an object in a object which only can have a string or array though (or even more nested objects)

Problem is now that 1.) and 2.) work but as soon as I add "$ref" to the "object" to get 3.) my validation server crashes with a stack overflow.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "patternProperties": {
            ".*": {
              "$ref": "#/properties/value"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The line `"$ref": "#/properties/value"` breaks my code.

How do I get this to work ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself. The line `"$ref": "#/properties/value"` has to be changed to `"$ref": "#/properties"`

I thought that #/properties would mean only the property "value" is allowed inside these objects which is not what I wanted. I wanted to have the contents of "value" so I went one step deeper.

Looks like `"$ref": "#/properties"` doesn't mean that only "value" is allowed instead it means only the properties of "value".

Comment: "#/properties" is just an empty schema, "value" is not a validation keyword. What you need (most likely) is "$ref": "#".

Comment: Also `"patternProperties": {".*": <schema>}` is the same as `"additionalProperties": <schema>`, just less efficient.